# Convert triangles to quads of a Mesh

Tags: c#, 3d-meshes

Supposing I have applied delaunay triangulation on a convex mesh, and I have all information (edges, vertices etc.) I would like to transform the triangles to quads

I was reading that inverse process, quad to triangle, one takes the vertices like:

```
quad 1 2 3 4
==>
triangle 1 2 3
triangle 3 4 1
```

each time we read a quad (4 vertices), we transform it to 2 triangles using these 4 vertices.

What would be the best approach to do triangles to quad?

I was thinking on pairing together adjacent triangular elements, and converting them into
quadrilateral elements by eliminating their shared edges
[image]

Do you know any sample code, would be best in c#

Comment: Is this for an arbitrary triangle mesh (as your diagram implies)? Or for a mesh that was originally quads? And what is the intended purpose? Are there any restrictions on the end result? Fewest quads? Most square-ish quads? etc...

Comment: Also, for anyone interested, there's a cross-post on Stack Overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23588263/165500).

Comment: The mesh is the result of delaunay triangulization, however I would like to substitute at least 2 triangles by one quad whenever possible

Comment: @cMinor: What for do you want quads exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Any 2 triangles that share an edge and have identical normals (or are very close) can be candidates for turning into a quad. The pseudo code for something like this would be:

`List triangleList;
List quadList;`

foreach(Triangle currentTriangle in triangleList)
{
  foreach(Triangle checkTriangle in triangleList)
  {
    if (currentTriangle != checkTriangle && 
        currentTriangle.sharesEdge(checkTriangle) == true &&
        currentTriangle.normal.dotProduct(checkTriangle.normal) > 0.99)
    {
      quadList.add(makeQuad(currentTriangle, checkTriangle));
      triangleList.remove(currentTriangle);
      triangleList.remove(checkTriangle);
      break;
    }
  }
}

This solution wouldn't give you the ideal list of quads, but it will be good enough in most cases. Where this solution would give a less than ideal solution would be in the case below:

[image: Triangle strip]

I've numbered the triangles here. Assuming they are all co-planar, you could certainly end up with a quad consisting of triangles 2 & 3, and then 2 triangles that can't be turned into quads with 1 & 4. The ideal solution of course would be 1 & 2 being a quad and 3 & 4 being another quad. I haven't done the math to prove it, but I think your worst case would be in a completely flat plane, you could end up with half quads and half triangles when the whole thing could be quads. Either way, it's a difficult problem to solve and the performance implications are likely to be negligible, so it's probably best to not bother optimizing.